# DTLS CertificateVerify doubt

Tags: tls, cryptography

In DTLS 1.2 RFC 6347, section 4.2.6:

> CertificateVerify and Finished messages have the same format as in TLS.  Hash calculations include entire handshake messages, including DTLS-specific fields: message_seq, fragment_offset, and fragment_length.

Is this the case for DTLS 1.0 as well? Cause I can't find info particularly for CertificateVerify in the specs for DTLS 1.0

How's the signature hash generated in DTLS 1.0? I tried hash all the message (Handshake layer) received from ClientHello to the one before CertificateVerify (Either with or without the cookie exchange) and it fails to do a verification on server. Did I miss any step?